# modify an nsmutablearray in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` of seven bools in managerViewController, these represent days of the week when a shop is open. I am running out of space in this view and most of the time the user will be happy with the default setting of open all hours.

the user needs to be able to change them to suit their business needs, my current approach to this is to have a uitableview of seven rows all of which have switches in them. where I am stuck is how to the actions of in uitableview modify the original nsmuntable array in the manageViewController class.

I am new to iOS, but I have built the `UITableView` and all the other bits, it is just accessing the `NSMutableArray` I am stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` or, with the new objective-c literals it's much easier:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
myArray[0] = @(YES); // the same as: [myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
myArray[0] = @(NO); // the same as: [myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a delegate to your table view controller, say`TableViewControllerDelegate`. Add a delegate property to your table view controller
    @property (weak, nonatomic) id delegate;

Make your `ManagerViewController` conform to the delegate protocol, and upon showing `TableViewController`, set its delegate to be your `ManagerViewController` instance.

Add a method in the delegate to inform the action on a day, for example:

```
- (void) didModifyDay:(NSInteger)dayNumber;
```

or

```
- (void) didChangeDay:(NSInteger)dayNumber toState:(BOOL)selected;
```

Comment: thanks for this mohannad, so i have it clear, set the deligate in the table view method to point to a delegate that sits in the managerViewController, which by default has access to that array.

Comment: To be exact. You're gonna make the `ManagerViewController` the delegate of the tableView. So whenever a change happens in the table view controller, the `ManagerViewController` will know about that change via the delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

When table view is loading in the

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

make sure to check initial values for all of the switch and set values from your data source (the mutable array). For easily handle the situation use a custom and put its object in the array.

```
@interface Days : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *day;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isOpen;
@end
```

i.e.

```
for(int ii = 0; ii < 7; ii++ ){
    Days *days = [[Days alloc] initWithDay:ii isOpen:YES];
    [array addObject:days];
    [days release];  
}
```

Assume that you have a custom UITableViewCell which have a property set to the switch.
i am using cell.switch for example.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"reusableCells";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
   if(cell == nil)
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];

    Days *days = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = days.day;
    [cell.switch setOn:days.isOpen animated:YES];

    return cell;
}
```

and this will handle your switch.
now assume you toggle the switch on/off when press the table cell so handle the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method  of the tableview delegate

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Days *days = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    days.isOpen != days.isOpen;
    [cell.switch setOn:days.isOpen animated:YES];
}
```

That's all. you will get the switch toggle on/off and the will be manipulated from the array.

Comment: ashim, thanks for the answer, in the code you have kindly put above, in the tableview delegate, which is described in managerViewController? or is the another way of manipulating a nasmutable array from another class?

Comment: You can use it in your managerViewController. You can get the days object directly from the array. Im just giving you some light and knowledge to you but you have put it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the app delegate class of your application to access the NSMutableArray.

In the app delegate class create the property for the class in which that NSMutableArray is present for e.g let say class name is TestController.

```
//then in .h file of Appdelegate

#import TestController.h

//in the interface 

TestController *objTest;

//declare the property
@property (nonatomic, strong) TestController *objTest;


//then in the .m file of app delegate synthesize the object
@synthesize objTest;
```

Now in the similar way declare the property for NSMutableArray in the TestController

Create the share instance of the app delegate class where you want to access the NSMutable array object(say arr1) as below

```
AppDelegate *objAppDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

You can access that array as "objAppDelegate.objTest.arr1"

Or

You can create the share instance in the view controller class

```
//in the .h of view controller
+ (id)sharedInstance;

//in the .m of view controller

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    // structure used to test whether the block has completed or not
    static dispatch_once_t p = 0;

    // initialize sharedObject as nil (first call only)
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;

    // executes a block object once and only once for the lifetime of an application
    dispatch_once(&p, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });


    // returns the same object each time
    return _sharedObject;
}
```

Then in the application where you fill the array use,

```
TestViewController *objTest=[TestViewController sharedInstance];
objTest.arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1", nil];
```

And in the table view controller you can access it as below

```
TestViewController *objTest=[TestViewController sharedInstance];
```

objTest.arr1 will be the resulted array.

Comment: in addsiteViewController i have nsmutablearray *days and addsiteViewontroller *site. in my tableViewController i am trying to acces the array with  AddsiteViewController *shared=(AddsiteViewController *)][[uiapplication sharedApplication]deligate]; then [shared.site.daysoftheweek count]; but this is causing a crash? what i am i missing?

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] wiil return the application delegate not view controller. so it always got crashed. Either you use the solution given by me or try to create the shared instance of the controller class by creating shareInstance method.